# How is it that community bot posted a 500 rep bounty a quesiton?

Tags: bug

Does community bot normally do this? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The community bot does many wondrous things, but setting a bounty is not one of them.

In this case, the bounty was set by the user who asked the question on their own question. Since they deleted their account in the meantime and the user does not exist anymore, the open bounty had to be linked to an existing account, which is by default the community bot.

Now, what happens with the bounty, then? As the help center helpfully mentions:

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount (or the full amount, if the answer is also accepted). If two or more eligible answers have the same score (their scores are tied), the oldest answer is chosen. If there's no answer meeting those criteria, no bounty is awarded to anyone.
>
> If the bounty was started by the question owner, and the question owner accepts an answer posted during the bounty period, and the bounty expires without an explicit award then we assume the bounty owner liked the answer they accepted and award it the full bounty amount at the time of bounty expiration.

Therefore  as EJoshuaS mentions in the comment section, part of or the whole bounty could even be awarded.

Comment: Won't half of the value of expiring bounties automatically be applied to the top question?

Comment: @EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine Thanks for reminding me of that possibility. Added a section on that.